# Coloring States in a D3.js Map

Tags: d3.js

I'm following this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922

I'm using the 500k version of the [U.S. States GeoJSON data](http://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/).
I haven't altered the code in any way thus far. Here's what my output looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the map is rendering as expected. The bubbles for cities are properly displaying. But the states aren't getting colored in.

The code is requesting (and finding) the proper stateslived.csv file, and there is nothing in the console.

I'm unsure what could be going wrong here, and I also don't have a clue how to debug a problem like this one.

Thanks! And feel free to edit the title if you can think of a more descriptive one.

Comment: In the example that you've referred to, do you see the logic behind coloring of the States? Do you see any specific property in the data that the code is looking for based on which the States are colored?

Comment: Okay, I think I see now. In the us-states.json file, each state is a "feature", and includes some data like: `{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0400000US02", "STATE": "02", "NAME": "Alaska", "LSAD": "", "CENSUSAREA": 570640.950000 }`, so I should add a property to each state called "visited"?

Comment: Thanks for your help - I was able to fix this with the above plus changing name to NAME in my JavaScript code.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help.